# Matching "camelCase" to a regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

```
String camelCasePattern = "([a-z][A-Z0-9]+)+";

boolean val = "camelCase".matches(camelCasePattern);
System.out.println(val);
```

The above prints false. I'm trying to match a camelCase pattern starting with lower case letter. I have tried to tweak it a bit, without no luck though. Is the pattern wrong for camelCase?

Comment: A missing `+` somewhere in between?

Comment: because you are only testing that the first character is lowercase in each match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go with:

```
String camelCasePattern = "([a-z]+[A-Z]+\\w+)+"; // 3rd edit, getting better
System.out.println("camelCaseCaseCCase5".matches(camelCasePattern));
```

**Output**

```
true
```

Your current `Pattern` is matching one lowercase followed by as many uppercase/digit, many times over, which is why it returns `false`.

Comment: you can still simplify by replacing `0-9` by `\\d`

Comment: Doesn't match 'camelCaseDOneWrong'. But can use it still :)

Comment: @D.Singh and Amit, I've fine-tuned my answer, that should improve it slightly.

Comment: I am not sure if the enclosing `(...)+` is necessary

Answer (score 2):

The best way to match your test case is:

```
String camelCasePattern = "^[a-z]+([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)+";
```

This will ensure it starts with a lowecase, and then has a repeating pattern of one capital letter, followed by some lowercase characters

Matches `camelCaseTest`  but not `camelCaseDOneWrong`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that a "camel case word" is defined as follows:

### "Camel case word" definition:

- Consists of only upper and lower case letters; `[A-Za-z]`.
- Must begin with a lower case letter; `[a-z]`.
- Must contain at least one upper case letter; `[A-Z]`.

The following tested Java program contains a fully commented regex that may be helpful:

```java
// TEST.java 20140529_0900
import java.util.regex.*;
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data =   "This has one camelCase word."+
                        "This hasTwo camelCaseWords."+
                        "NON CamelCase withDigits123 words.";
        Pattern re_camel_case_word = Pattern.compile(
            "  # Match one camelCase word.\n" +
            "  \\b       # Anchor to word boundary.                    \n" +
            "  [a-z]+    # Begin with one or more lowercase alphas.    \n" +
            "  (?:       # One or more parts starting with uppercase.  \n" +
            "    [A-Z]   # At least one uppercase alpha                \n" +
            "    [a-z]*  # followed by zero or more lowercase alphas.  \n" +
            "  )+        # One or more parts starting with uppercase.  \n" +
            "  \\b       # Anchor to word boundary.",
            Pattern.COMMENTS);
        Matcher matcher = re_camel_case_word.matcher(data);
        while (matcher.find())
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
}
```

Note that with this definition, digits and other non-alpha chars are not allowed. The pattern would need to be modified to accommodate other "camel case word" definitions.

Answer (score 2):

#### To be proper camel case (with digits allowed) a word:

- MUST start with a lower case alphabet (a through z)
- MUST have no spaces, punctuation or special characters
- CAN have *at most* 1 uppercase alphabet in a row
- MAY end in an uppercase alphabet
- MAY contain digits 0 - 9

This regex supports all these requirements:

```
String camelCasePattern = "^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*[A-Z]?|([a-z0-9]+[A-Z])*|[A-Z])$";
```

Test cases: https://regex101.com/library/8nQras

For more details on camel case and pascal case check out this [repo](https://github.com/roubles/casing).

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for `String camelCasePattern = "([a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+";`

Answer (score 0):

Try `([a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]*)*` or `([a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-z]+([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*$
```

matched:
small
smallLarge
smallLargeLarge
smallA1

not matched:
smallLARGE
camelCaseDOneWrong
camelCaseDWHDone